# Facebook library for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I'm trying to use some facebook datas (login, but mostly I'm trying to get the number of likes of a page in my database) in my ASP.NET projects.
Which tool/library/any possibly way should I use?
I googled a lot but all posts are unuseful or too old.
So there's something useful to integrate facebook datas on ASP.NET nowaday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Facebook SDK. You can request information from Facebook using this SDK

http://facebooksdk.net/docs/reference/SDK/